# How to change Call Button to Link Button

Tags: android

I just a newbie for android,
How to change call button became link button to twitter/facebook or link website

```
 // ------------ Call button---------------------
        private void call() {
            try {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Info.phoneNumber+""));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {

            }
        }

        public void btnPhone(View v) {

            try {

                call();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
```

Main

```
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="btnPhone" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/call" />
    </TableRow>
```

Info

```
public static String phoneNumber = "+xxxxxx";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update like...

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```